# Did James Blish just make up a bunch of scientific disciplines?

Tags: science, james-blish

In [*A Case of Conscience*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Case_of_Conscience) appears this quote:

> “You should see what they can do with mixed disciplines—scholia like histochemistry, immunodynamics, biophysics, terataxonomy, osmotic genetics, electrolimnology, and half a hundred more.”

Of the items in this list, histochemistry and biophysics are real things. The rest seem to be entirely made up. I have a difficult time even figuring out what they might mean. Is "terataxonomy" the categorization of monsters? Why would that be a scientific discipline?

A possible clue that this is some kind of joke is "scholia," a word that seems wholly out of place in this context, unless he's using it in a metaphorical way I don't understand.

Is he just messing with us? I haven't read much Blish; is this the kind of thing he does often? Just what *are* these sciences?

Comment: I have somewhat similar questions about this quote: “It’s a thoroughly liberal society in terms of guarantees, yet all the same it never even begins to tip over toward the side of total disorganization, toward the kind of Gandhiism that keeps a people tied to the momma-and-poppa farm and the roving-brigand distribution system.”  Is there something about Ghandi's ideas I've never heard of??

Comment: One of the skills of a fine SF writer is the ability to make science 'sing' as part of the story. It has to sound real -- more real than actual science -- to the reader who usually isn't a scientist. Blish was very, very good at that, scattering little details (that he'd picked up or made up) through his stories in a way that made it sound like the reader is being given a glimpse of the future. (And he "loved" the word 'scholia'. It turns up in several other stories.)

Comment: I should reword the title to indicate that I'd like to know what these disciplines would be, but I'm not quite sure how.

Comment: Assuming it does mean "taxonomy of monsters", terataxonomy is also conjugated wrong. It should be "teratotaxonomy". The prefix comes from the Greek τέρας, which is conjugated as "terato-" when used as a prefix.

Comment: Let's face it, with the ongoing differentiation of the sciences pretty much any combination could become real (if not already). Even pseudo-sciences like Asimov's psychohistory are fair game if used properly as a story vehicle or in those cases as a means to invoke scientific wonder awe.

Comment: @wp78de Given things like the Youtube algorithm, I'm not sure that psychohistory will remain a pseudoscience for much longer. It'd just be driven by Big Data AI systems.

Comment: It is worth recalling that Blish had a degree in Microbiology, and worked for a pharmaceutical corp for a time early in his career (which informs the setting of *They Shall Have Stars*) I suspect some of these are alternate coinages for real sub-specialties.

Comment: Blish also uses the word "scholium" for "discipline" in _They shall have stars_: 'Dimensional analysis wasn't the only scholium that would have to be revised [if the spindizzy proved to work]'.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

These appear to be a mix of real and invented disciplines.

### Real Ones

- **Histochemistry** is about the kinds of chemicals in your tissues. "Histo" here isn't related to history, but to "histology", a discipline that is interested in bodily tissues. Histologists are often experts in microscopy (microscope use) such as slide preperation and other techniques.
- **Biophysics** uses concepts and approaches from physics to understand biology.
- **Osmotic genetics** isn't a formal discipline, but there are people who study genetics with an eye toward this thing. It's broadly a part of microbiology, looking at how the amounts or concentrations of different substances are related to genetics.

### Presumed Invented Ones

These appear to be invented. You mentioned in a comment trying to understand what these disciplines may be, so  I've tried to sort out the parts of their names that would indicate what they are about. Of course, it's very speculative. "Electrolimnology is as electrolimnology does", and all that.

- **Immunodynamics**: The same suggests a relationship to our immune systems (immunology). Complexity theory (or complexity science) is a field which explores dynamic interactions in things. Perhaps this is an examination of the complex interactions related to the immune system.
- **Terataxonomy**: Teratology is a field of developmental biology which is interested in abnormalities related to development. This includes congenital birth defects, as well as abnormalities related to puberty and other stages of life. "Terataxonomy" implies some ordering or structuring ("taxis") of those abnormalities.
- **Electrolimnology**: Limnology is the study of fresh water, like lakes, rivers, streams, springs, etc. "Electrolimnology" implies some relationship to electricity. There are other fields and techniques which do this (like electrochemistry).

Comment: "Electrolimnology" seems to align with some pseudo-scientific explanations of things like [dowsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dowsing).

Comment: The OP was probably correct: Terataxonomy would refer to the classification of congenital abnormalities; their study in general is called teratology.

Comment: @InvisibleTrihedron Wonderful find! I'll edit that entry.

Comment: In 1958, "biophysics" was generally used only in the slightly more restricted sense "the study of the mechanical and electrical properties of the parts of living organisms" (definition per the *Oxford English Dictionary*).

Comment: "Osmotic genetics" is a meaningless combination of words and not a discipline. "Histochemistry" might be a discipline in some parallel universe, but not here. "Biophysics" is real. (I did a year's postdoc in a Biophysics department trying to compute hyperpolarizabilities of biomolecules.)

Comment: @MarkOlson I'm not a biologist, but if it was a real discipline, my immediate assumption would be the use of osmotic models to study horizontal gene transfer across microbial populations.

Comment: I interpreted (the hypothetical) "osmotic genetics" in exactly the same way as @nick012000: the study of phenomena such as conjugation.

Comment: It seems quite possible that Blish intended them all to be made up, but ended up using realistic enough names that he got a mixture of disciplines that actually did exist at the time, ones that have since come into existence, and ones that still don’t exist.

Comment: @MarkOlson The [Journal of Histochemistry and Cell Biology](https://www.springer.com/journal/418/) will be surprised to find out their discipline doesn't exist!

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- I struggled to characterize this subject. Any help would be appreciated. I searched Google scholar and found quite a lot of results which seemed to be a fair match, but it's a bit out of my subject-matter expertise.